# Command line help for : Updating a file to a specific older revision in SVN /Subversion?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I hope the subject line is clear.
I am aware of the command line  **svn update -r [REV]** updates my working copy to a specific revision. However i just want a specific file to update to that version.
Any help in this regard is deeply appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn help update` gives:

> usage: update [PATH...]
>
> If no revision given, bring working copy up-to-date with HEAD rev.
>    Else synchronize working copy to revision given by -r.

So, `svn update -r XXX path\to\file` should do it.